# Replacement of the Heredoc syntax

Tags: php, loops, foreach, heredoc

```
    foreach($array["$new"]['features'] as $key => $feature) :
      $features .= <<< ____EOT
        <li> $feature </li>
____EOT;
    endforeach;
```

Currently, I am using the heredoc syntax, but that has its drawbacks. Are there any other PHP methods to accomplish the same w/o using the Heredoc syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a string.

```
$features .= "<li> $feature </li>";
```

Heredoc has the advantage that you don't have to worry about escaping quotes inside the value, so it's very useful for long blocks of HTML.

Comment: This is one of the most basic features of the language. Heredoc is the advanced option.

Comment: But Herdoc have space issue.

Comment: If it's a large block of HTML, an extra line is not a big deal.